# CodeIgniter/sqlsrv/MSSQL Update-Queries contain Id-column - Error

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have a hard time migrating a WebApp from a Unix/Apache/MySQL System to Win2012/Apache/MSSQL. First I installed the sqlsrv-stuff you need and the connection works.
BUT:
update queries cause error mesages like

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 42000/8102
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Die
>   id-Identitätsspalte kann nicht aktualisiert werden." The last part
>   basically means "The ID-identy column may not be updated."

The generated update-query looks like this:

```
UPDATE "dbo"."table" SET "id" = 1, "someStuff" = 5 WHERE "id" = 1
```

---

My models use statements like:

```
$data = array (
   'someStuff' => (int) $stuff
);
$this->db->update('table',$data,"id = ".$itemID);
```

---

I understand the message as the statement contains a SET "id" which is obviously irrelevant as the id-field is an auto-increment thing generated in mssql - and as you see, I am not including it in my model. How do I get `Codeigniter` to reduce the `UPDATE`-statement to not contain primary keys? Or is there another easy way to resolve this?

If it helps, I might as well modify `Codeigniter` to check if the internally generated query contains an `id` field in order to skip these, as they are always auto-incremented primary keys, but my attempts to do so weren't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If id is an auto-increment field, don't include it in the Codeigniter Insert/Update query. It should be added automatically. Just Insert/Update the other values on the DB
Rem: Auto-increment attribute is set on the Database level not on the Codeigniter.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't me who includes the ID-field, it is codeigniter. 
As i wrote, i am aware of the situation, but I cant fix it. :(

Comment: Your query is wrong. Does this sound right to you? Update tb_name Set $id = 1 where $id =1 ;

Comment: No, this does not sound right so far. As I mentioned twice now, I am aware of the situation and and - as I mentioned twice now - it isn't me who includes the id column in the query. "My" query is what happens in the model  -  you will see that id occurs exactly once and that is where the ´where´-clause is put in (´"id = ".$itemID´).
My problem is that somewhere during the process codeigniter adds the id-column, and I wanted to know how to prevent this.

Comment: Share your full original query plus even your sample data

Comment: Boy, this is getting ugly. As I found out, someone made undocumented last-minute changes during the migration and found out that the data-array did not contain the id - and for a reason I'll never understand he thought it would be a great idea to put them in. 

Sorry sorry for the confusion! Confused

Lessons learned:



    -CI works fine even with SQLSRV,


    -I'll have to make sure that the code I create is uploaded as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, someone made undocumented last-minute changes during the migration and found out that the data-array did not contain the id - and for a reason I'll never understand he thought it would be a great idea to put them in.

Sorry sorry for the confusion!

Lessons learned:

1. CI works fine even with SQLSRV,
2. I'll have to make sure that the code I create is uploaded as I wanted it to be.